# Amazon Food slot type identifies drug name as food

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I am in process of developing Lex Bot and using inbuilt custom slot as Amazon.Food

While testing the bot if I ask a question :

```
Can I ....... Advil ....
```

Advil is considered as a food item.

Does Amazon.Food include common drugs as well ? Unfortunately I can not access list of Amazon.Food

Comment: [Amazon developer forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=251&start=0) will be better place to ask this question.

Comment: It sounds like this is leading up to another question. So what if I told you "Advil" can fill the slot whether or not it is in the list for `AMAZON.Food`...maybe you can include your follow-up question to that.

Comment: @JayA.Little yes i think Lex's machine learning algo will try to detect the keyword based on many factors including how the sentence is formed, what are the surrounding words (and their types etc). it is not necessarily present in some list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requesting to peek behind the curtain of the built-in slot types are a common question.  The people from Amazon tell us 2 things in response:

1) Amazon has not made any of these built-in slot type lists available to the public.

2) These built-in slot types are not limited to the words/phrases in their lists.

So "Advil" could fill the slot for `AMAZON.Food` whether it is a part of the list or not.

About Built-in SlotTypes: They do give a few descriptions and examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/howitworks-builtins-slots.html) for Lex. Then that refers you to the full list [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html), even though it's meant for Alexa. (The only difference, as of this writing, is that you can extend the built-in slot types in Alexa development but not in Lex.)

Comment: this is why it is always better to handle slots in lambda code for such situations.

Comment: @sid8491 agreed, and that is most likely where this question is headed: how to restrict the built-in slot types? -> handle in lambda code.

Comment: yes, and in this case we can use some third party API or some logic for validation where if `slot` is identified as `Advil` we will `nullify` the slot and send `elicitslot` with message "we do not support Advil" or something like that. just an idea.

Comment: Yes we are handling this in lambda Code and verifying it with external sources